# unordered list xsl - bullet not showed

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm creating an XSL template to show by an XML a bullet list but bullets are not showed
this is my XSL

```
<xsl:template match="unorderedList">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="listitem">
            <li>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./para"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

and this is my XML

```
<unorderedList>
    <listitem>
        <para><literal>First item</literal></para>
    </listitem>
    <listitem>
        <para><literal>Second item</literal></para>
    </listitem>
</unorderedList>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `>` on `</unorderedList`

Comment: @ScottieG where?

Comment: @PrinceVegeta where?

Comment: @CristinaMoretti - Your code has been edited by Sanjay since my comment.

Comment: @PrinceVegeta doesen't work :/

Comment: The XML and XSLT snippet you have shown should "work". See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq7d. Can you say what result you are actually getting when you try? It might help if you showed more of your XSLT as maybe something else is causing the template not to be matched. Also ensure the XML in your question truly represents the XML you are using. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `for-each` I'd recommend to familiarize yourself with matching templates to handle the entire structure.

Your current approach misses the `<literal>` element containing the text you expect to be rendered as your `<li>` content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- usually start out with matching the document root -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- ... and pass on to the next matching template -->
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- your matching ul element -->
    <xsl:template match="unorderedList">
        <ul>
            <!-- ... pass on to the list content -->
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
     </xsl:template>

     <!-- nothing to do at this level -->
     <xsl:template match="listitem">
         <!-- ... pass on -->
         <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:template>

     <!-- nothing to do at this level -->
     <xsl:template match="para">
         <!-- ... pass on -->
         <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:template>

     <!-- we reached the li content! --->
     <xsl:template match="literal">
         <li>
             <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
         </li>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What problem does this solve? Most of the added templates are redundant.

Comment: My intention is (as mentioned) to show matching templates. Of course this is very verbose but OP is clearly a learner so trying to show the whole process flow doesn't hurt.

Comment: I thought the intention was to solve the problem presented in the question.

Comment: As Tim C already pointed out in his comment, there is no problem - at least not in the example shown. I still think this answer can help fixing the OPs actual code and probably solve the real issue not shown here.

Comment: "*there is no problem*" Exactly. Which makes your answer not only useless, but also misleading.